# Why does an unexecuted eval have an effect on behavior in some browsers?

Tags: javascript

Let's suppose I have these two functions:

```
function change(args) {
    args[0] = "changed";
    return " => ";
}
function f(x) {
    return [x, change(f.arguments), x];
}
console.log(f("original"));
```

In most browsers, except Opera, this returns `["original", " => ", "original"]`.

But if I change the `f` function like this,

```
function f(x) {
    return [x, change(f.arguments), x];
    eval("");
}
```

it will return `["original", " => ", "changed"]` in IE9, Safari 5, and Firefox 16 and 17.

If I replace `eval("")` with `arguments`, it will also change in Chrome.

You can [test it on your own browser on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jENnC/)

I don't understand this behavior at all. If the function returns before those statements are executed, how can those statements affect the return value? Even if the statements were executed, why would they have any effect on argument mutation?

Comment: Why would use use eval in the first place? There is a better solution than `eval` 99.9999% of the time.

Comment: Undefined behaviour (dunno if the term is used much in the context of JS)

Comment: @epascarello: This question isn't about using `eval`, it's about the strange behavior that it causes in this case.

Comment: @epascarello: This has nothing to do with the functional uses of `eval()`. The fact of the matter is that the presence of `eval()` is causing unintended side effects, and the OP wants to know why.

Comment: @jli I've read the spec before, and I don't recall any case like this being mentioned as undefined behavior. I can't imagine how this behavior is even defensible--unexecuted statements should never have any effect.

Comment: @Cory but they found out about it because of using eval(). Just stating that there is a way around the bug in the browser by not using it.

Comment: @epascarello: Why are you assuming it's a bug? We don't have definitive evidence for that yet. It may be part of the spec, or undefined behavior, and that's the whole point of this question - to find out what it happening.

Comment: @epascarello: `eval()` isn't the only thing that causes the behavior. Generally you are correct, one shouldn't use `eval()`. It contributes information to the example, however.

Comment: @PeterOlson: Seems that, at least on IE, any argument whatsoever passed to `eval()` will augment the arguments, not just an empty string. I wonder if `eval()` is modifying something globally or variable-environmently. To do so, it would have to be executed before the function returns. I can't find anything in the spec that would suggest such behavior.

Comment: @PeterOlson I think jli's point is that the spec allows both `["original", " => ", "original"]` and `["original", " => ", "changed"]`, and when both are allowed, you cannot rely on getting any particular result, it may be affected by changes that intuitively shouldn't affect anything. I don't know what the spec says, so I don't know if that interpretation is correct.

Comment: @hvd Specs do not allow both evaluations. [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), on page 64, specifies left-to-right evaluation order of array initializer elements; `change(f.arguments)` _has_ to be evaluated before the last `x` reference, so `x` should already be changed for the last element of the array.

Comment: just be written `f.arguments` instead of the more normal `arguments` you have moved into some some special unknown place

Comment: Thanks @Peter. I'm studying the ES5 specs, and answering your question made me dive deeper into some sections. Unfortunately, the answer is not there!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> #### TL;DR
>
> The likely cause is the interaction of the non-standard `function.arguments` with browser optimizations for function code containing `eval` and/or `arguments`. However, only people familiar with the implementation details on each browser would be able to explain the *why* in depth.

The main problem here appears to be the use of the non-standard `Function.prototype.arguments`. When you don't use it, the strange behavior goes away.

The specification only mentions the [`arguments` object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6), and never says it might be treated as a property, prefixed with `[funcName].`. I'm not sure where that came from, but it's probably something pre-ES3, kept on browsers for backward compatibility. As Cory's answer states, that use is [now discouraged on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments). [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/he95z461(v=vs.94).aspx), however, doesn't say anything against it. I also found it mentioned on this [specification for compatibility between browsers](http://mathias.html5.org/specs/javascript/#function.prototype.arguments)<sup>*</sup>, which does not appear to be implemented consistently by vendors (no browser pass all [tests](http://mathias.html5.org/tests/javascript/function/)). Also, using `arguments` as a property of the function is not allowed in strict mode (again, that's not in the ECMA specs, and IE9 seems to ignore the restriction).

Then come `eval` and `arguments`. [As you are aware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12391378/825789), the ECMAScript specification requires some [extra](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2) [operations](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6) to be performed so those language constructs can be used (in the case of `eval`, the operation is different depending on the call being [direct](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.1.1) or not). Since those operations can have an impact on performance, (some?) JavaScript engines perform optimizations to avoid them if `eval` or `arguments` are not used. Those optimizations, combined with the use of a non-standard property of the `Function` object, seem to be what's causing the strange results you got. Unfortunately, I don't know the implementation details for each browser, so I can't give you a precise answer on *why* we see those collateral effects.

<sup>(*) Spec written by an [SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96656/mathias-bynens), by the way.</sup>

#### Tests

I ran some tests to see how `eval` (direct and indirect calls), `arguments` and `fn.arguments` interact on IE, Firefox and Chrome. It's not surprising that the results vary on each browser, since we're dealing with the non-standard `fn.arguments`.

The first test just checks for strict equality of `fn.arguments` and `arguments`, and if the presence of `eval` affects that in any way. Inevitably, my Chrome tests are contamined by the presence of `arguments`, which has an effect on the results, as you said in the question. Here are the results:

```
                       |  no eval  |  direct eval call  |  indirect eval call
-----------------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------------
IE 9.0.8112.16421      |  true     |  true              |  true
FF 16.0.2              |  false    |  false             |  false
Chrome 22.0.1229.94    |  true     |  false             |  true
```

You can see IE and Firefox are more consistent: the objects are always equal on IE, and never equal on Firefox. In Chrome, however, they're only equal if the function code does not contain a direct `eval` call.

The remaining tests are assignment tests based on functions that look like the following:

```
function fn(x) {
    // Assignment to x, arguments[0] or fn.arguments[0]
    console.log(x, arguments[0], fn.arguments[0]);
    return; // make sure eval is not actually called
    // No eval, eval(""), or (1,eval)("")
}
```

Below are the results for each tested browser.

**Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421**

```
                             | no eval                   | direct eval call          | indirect eval call
-----------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------
arguments[0] = 'changed';    | changed, changed, changed | changed, changed, changed | changed, changed, changed
x = 'changed';               | changed, changed, changed | changed, changed, changed | changed, changed, changed
fn.arguments[0] = 'changed'; | changed, changed, changed | changed, changed, changed | changed, changed, changed
```

First of all, it seems my IE tests give different results than what is stated in the question; I always get "changed" on IE. Maybe we used different IE builds? Anyway, what the results above show is that IE is the most consistent browser. As on IE `arguments === fn.arguments` is always true, `x`, `arguments[0]` or `function.arguments[0]` all point to the same value. If you change any of them, all three will output the same changed value.

**Firefox 16.0.2**

```
                             | no eval                      | direct eval call          | indirect eval call
-----------------------------+------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------
arguments[0] = 'changed';    | changed, changed, original   | changed, changed, changed | changed, changed, original
x = 'changed';               | changed, changed, original   | changed, changed, changed | changed, changed, original
fn.arguments[0] = 'changed'; | original, original, original | changed, changed, changed | original, original, original
```

Firefox 16.0.2 is less consistent: although `arguments` is *never* `=== fn.arguments` on Firefox, `eval` has an effect on the assignments. Without a direct call to `eval`, changing `arguments[0]` changes `x` too, but does not change `fn.arguments[0]`. Changing `fn.arguments[0]` does not change either `x` or `arguments[0]`. It was a complete surprise that changing `fn.arguments[0]` does not change itself!

When `eval("")` is introduced, the behavior is different: changing one of `x`, `arguments[0]` or `function.arguments[0]` starts affecting the other two. So it's like `arguments` becomes `=== function.arguments` – except that it does not, Firefox still says that `arguments === function.arguments` is `false`. When an indirect `eval` call is used instead, Firefox behaves as if there were no `eval`.

**Chrome 22.0.1229.94**

```
                             | no eval                    | direct eval call             | indirect eval call
-----------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------
arguments[0] = 'changed';    | changed, changed, changed  | changed, changed, original   | changed, changed, changed
x = 'changed';               | changed, changed, changed  | changed, changed, original   | changed, changed, changed
fn.arguments[0] = 'changed'; | changed, changed, changed  | original, original, original | changed, changed, changed
```

Chrome's behavior is similar to Firefox's: when there is no `eval` or an indirect `eval` call, it behaves consistently. With the direct `eval` call, the link between `arguments` and `fn.arguments` seem to break (which makes sense, considering `arguments === fn.arguments` is `false` when `eval("")` is present). Chrome also presents the weird case of `fn.arguments[0]` being `original` even after assignment, but it happens when `eval("")` is present (while on Firefox it happens when there's no `eval`, or with the indirect call).

Here is the full code for the tests, if anyone wants to run them. There's also a [live version on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujzKq/).

```
function t1(x) {
    console.log("no eval: ", arguments === t1.arguments);
}
function t2(x) {
    console.log("direct eval call: ", arguments === t2.arguments);
    return;
    eval("");
}
function t3(x) {
    console.log("indirect eval call: ", arguments === t3.arguments);
    return;
    (1, eval)("");
}
    
// ------------
    
function t4(x) {
    arguments[0] = 'changed';
    console.log(x, arguments[0], t4.arguments[0]);
}
    
function t5(x) {
    x = 'changed';
    console.log(x, arguments[0], t5.arguments[0]);
}
    
function t6(x) {
    t6.arguments[0] = 'changed';
    console.log(x, arguments[0], t6.arguments[0]);
}
    
// ------------
    
function t7(x) {
    arguments[0] = 'changed';
    console.log(x, arguments[0], t7.arguments[0]);
    return;
    eval("");
}
    
function t8(x) {
    x = 'changed';
    console.log(x, arguments[0], t8.arguments[0]);
    return;
    eval("");
}
    
function t9(x) {
    t9.arguments[0] = 'changed';
    console.log(x, arguments[0], t9.arguments[0]);
    return;
    eval("");
}
    
// ------------
    
function t10(x) {
    arguments[0] = 'changed';
    console.log(x, arguments[0], t10.arguments[0]);
    return;
    (1, eval)("");
}
    
function t11(x) {
    x = 'changed';
    console.log(x, arguments[0], t11.arguments[0]);
    return;
    (1, eval)("");
}
    
function t12(x) {
    t12.arguments[0] = 'changed';
    console.log(x, arguments[0], t12.arguments[0]);
    return;
    (1, eval)("");
}
    
// ------------
    
console.log("--------------");
console.log("Equality tests");
console.log("--------------");
t1('original');
t2('original');
t3('original');
    
console.log("----------------");
console.log("Assignment tests");
console.log("----------------");
console.log('no eval');
t4('original');
t5('original');
t6('original');
console.log('direct call to eval');
t7('original');
t8('original');
t9('original');
console.log('indirect call to eval');
t10('original');
t11('original');
t12('original');
```

Answer (score 3):

Just playing around, I found that you remove the `f.` from the `f.arguments` value in the array, and just use `arguments`, the behavior is the same no matter what comes after the `return`:

```
function f(x) {
    return [x, change(arguments), x];
}
function g(x) {
    return [x, change(arguments), x];
    eval("");
}
function h(x) {
    return [x, change(arguments), x];
    arguments;
}
```

In all three cases using `x = "original"`, the output is:

```
["original", " => ", "changed"]
["original", " => ", "changed"] 
["original", " => ", "changed"]
```

In this case, values are modified by `change()` as if the `arguments` array is passed by reference. To keep "original" *unchanged*, I might suggest converting the `arguments` object to an actual array first (thus passing `arguments`' elements *by value*):

```
function h(x) {
    var argsByValue = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return [x, change(argsByValue), x];
}
```

In the above example, `x` will remain "original" before and after `change()`, because a copy of `x` was modified, not the original.

I'm still not sure what the effects of having `eval("");` or `arguments;` are, but your question is still interesting, as are the results.

What's really strange is that this even affects putting the `change()` in its own function scope with a copy of the function arguments

```
function f(x) {
    return ((function(args) {             
        return [x, change(args), x];
    })(f.arguments));
    // the presence of the line below still alters the behavior
    arguments; 
}
```

It seems that a **reference** to `f.arguments` still holds in this case. Weird stuff.

**UPDATES**

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments):

> The `arguments` object is a local variable available within all functions; **`arguments` as a property of `Function` can no longer be used.**

Seems like, at least for Firefox, you shouldn't be using `arguments` as a property (e.g. `function foo() { var bar = foo.arguments; }`), though they don't say why.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/WzbN4/2/ `foo.arguments === arguments` in Chrome in all except the one with `eval`. Firefox returns false in all 3. Weird stuff.

Comment: Also, with strict mode on, `change(foo.arguments)` is not allowed, but `change(arguments)` *is* allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some excellent Javascript nuances coming into effect:

```
change(f.arguments)
change(x)
```

The former passes the argument list into change() *as a reference*. Arrays tend to be references in Javascript. This means that if you change an element of an array somewhere else, those changes will be applied wherever you use *that same array*.

The latter passes the argument x *as a value*. It's like handing off a copy - change can change it around and it will only affect the local variable. Because x is a string, and strings are immutable, args[0] = "changed" in the change() function doesn't do anything. Try the following in a console:

```
var x = "asdf";
x[0] = "foo";
console.log(x); // should print "asdf"
```

In the f, h, g functions, the value of arguments[0] is changed in the second index in the returned list. The third index will return "changed".

Theoretically. However, some browsers compile Javascript, which causes kind-of race conditions and instructions may not execute in the order you type them, especially if they are on the same line and you're changing the stack and accessing it from the same line.

```
return [x, change(f.arguments), x];
```

...attempts to change the arguments variable and access x (which is an argument) at the same time. In Chrome, for instance, passing f.arguments to change() results in ["original", " => ", "original"] while passing just arguments results in ["original", " => ", "changed"]. It may also be a scoping issue and how Javascript handles value and reference types, but that behaviour is different across browsers.

I didn't see any odd behaviour with eval() given what I've described, but it seems that stating arguments in the h() function after the return creates a side-effect that I suspect is caused by Chrome's compilation of Javascript. What's really interesting is that internally, the shell executes a variable by returning its value, but it's not being written anywhere, expect perhaps to a cache. Hard to tell what's going on in Javascript's stack, but what you're doing is certainly unconventional and it will for sure mess up the compiler across browsers.

EDIT:

Even better:
    console.log(h.arguments);
    return [x, change(arguments), x];
    arguments

will log

```
["changed"]
["original", " => ", "changed"]
```

Sure looks like a race condition, or some wonky passing of references to the arguments array within functions!

Comment: `arguments` is not an array, and browsers are not allowed to reorder evaluation in array initializers; the evaluation order there is explicitly specified in ECMA-262. You're also misusing the term "race condition"; there is no multithreading involved in JS, so no race conditions are possible.