# Why are unexecuted statements slowing down my functions?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have created four different functions, like this:

```
var normal = function() {
    return;
};
var control = function() {
    return;
    alert("Hello, world!");
};
var withArguments = function() {
    return;
    arguments;
};
var withEval = function() {
    return;
    eval("");
};
```

Since they all just do nothing and immediately return, I would expect all of them to have the same speed. But, after [testing it on jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/unexecuted-statements-after-return), I find that `normal` and `control` execute about the same, but `withArguments` and `withEval` execute much more slowly.

Why would these unexecuted statements have any performance impact? Since they're never executed, how is it possible for them to have any effect?

Comment: How do different browser/javascript engines handle your test scripts?

Comment: I'm not sure it will make a difference, but have you run tests where the functions return a value?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In short, calling `eval` inside of a function and being able to access the `arguments` array both use extra set-up during function invocation. If it is known that neither `arguments` nor `eval` will be executed, this extra set-up can be skipped.

The compiler does not attempt to predict whether or not the `arguments` array will actually be accessed or whether `eval` will actually be called, it only checks whether or not they exist in the function.

### `arguments`

It is more expensive during runtime to invoke a variadic function that uses the `arguments` object than a "normal" function that doesn't use the `arguments` object.

The extra steps required to bind the execution environment when the `arguments` object is declared are [specified in §10.6 of the ECMA-262 standard](http://es5.github.io/#x10.6). Creating the `arguments` object is a somewhat expensive 15-step process. Basically, `arguments` has to be populated with the passed-in arguments, and the `.caller` and `.callee` properties have to be created.

The standard says that the `arguments` object should be created when a function enters its execution context, unless there is already a parameter, variable, or function declared inside the function named `arguments`.

For purposes of optimization, most browsers do not actually create the arguments object unless the function actually uses it somewhere (even after a `return`). This is why you see a performance hit when `arguments` is referenced, even when lines containing it are never executed.

### `eval`

Entering `eval` code, as [specified in §10.4.2 of the ECMA-262 standard](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.2), requires creating a special execution context. Basically, it has to bind all the properties of the calling function's execution context to the `eval` context.

If there are multiple `eval`s called in one function, they will basically both be doing the same process twice. For optimization, if browsers detect that there is an `eval` in the function (even after a `return`), it pre-populates this new execution context that every `eval` can use, so that it doesn't need to be recreated multiple times.

---

**Note that these optimizations are browser dependent and not required by the standard**, so some browsers might not actually perform the optimizations described, or they might do things differently.

Comment: +1 for the great answer. FWIW, I ran the tests on IE10, and the `withArguments()` test ran as quickly as the `normal()` and `control()`; so I assume IE10 delays the setup in this instance until it's actually needed.

Comment: That method of invoking `eval()` will also execute it within global scope. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yt2mH/)