# Why element argument in link function of directive is undefined in $watch?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a simple directive which triggers focus event on input to show tooltip

```
.directive('tooltipValidationObserver', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            $scope.$watch(function() { return ngModel.$invalid; }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $('#' + attrs.id).trigger('focus');
                });
            });
        }
    }
}])
```

It works perfectly if I use attrs.id, but if I want to perform

```
$(element).trigger('focus')
```

element is undefined, when in link function it's defined on linking phase.. and undefined in watch function.  Why? In watch function I can obtain all available variables (such as $scope, attrs, ngModel) but not the element..

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you simply want `element.trigger('focus')`. `element` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: did u try to `console.log()` the `element` inside `link` function as , `console.log(element)` ?

Comment: Yes of course, thanks, I forget that element is already jquery object

Comment: K.Toress, yes! That variable exists when I tried to log it to console.. Before I set breakpoint in chrome developer tools in code to see that variable and it's was undefined.. So, now I don't understand why that variable in chrome developer tools available only if I use it. I mean when I perform debugging with breakpoints in the inner $watch function.  Magic.

Comment: @champion I have run into that problem before as well and it can be frustrating.  Check out this explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388530/why-does-chrome-debugger-think-closed-local-variable-is-undefined

Comment: @ken4z thank's for information! yes it not so obvious and very confusing..

Comment: So is this question only debugger related? Otherwise you might want to replicate the issue in Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/EZLm5Q3IXlTusfqKZvcP?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

use,

```
$(element[0]).trigger('focus');
```

in the link function `element` is the  `jqLite-wrapped element`, try to `console.log(element)` and expand the output and you can see the `0` index is the actual dom element. here is a [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

get the actual dom element by `element[0]` and we create `jquery` reference as `$(element[0])` to that element and trigger the focus event on it. hope this helps.