# ES6 immediately invoke recursive arrow function

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

This is my current code:

```
const fn = parameter => {
    // if, else ...
    fn(X);
};
fn(0);
```

Now, I can't use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589488/es6-immediately-invoked-arrow-function) as I need to call the function with a parameter and it must be callable recursively.

How to refactor the above arrow function to be immediately invoked and recursively callable?

Comment: Don't use an arrow function?

Answer (score 19):

JavaScript provides a great solution for recursive functions: *named function expressions*. Hence I would recommend to use that instead of an arrow function:

```
(function fn(parameter) {
  // if, else ...
  fn(x);
})(0);
```

Comment: great answer. goes to show that arrow functions are not always better than named function expressions.

Answer (score 12):

First, let me put the disclaimer that Immediately-Invoked-Function-Expressions (IIFE) are [considered bad practice](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/5-javascript-bad-parts-that-are-fixed-in-es6-c7c45d44fd81#.9ejjg9kia) in ES6, and this is tail-recursion and personally I would change it to a for loop.

but you can always do this I guess:

```
((x) =>{ const fn=(p)=>{
       //whatever
       fn(q)
   }
   fn(x)
})(0)
```

Comment: The article you reference doesn't say anywhere that IIFE's are "bad practice", nor does it provide any evidence for that statement. It only states that features of ECMAScript 2015 can be used as an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to call recursive an `lambda expression` or `anonymous function` you need [**Y combinator**](https://blog.jcoglan.com/2008/01/10/deriving-the-y-combinator/). For more details you can read [**http://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html**](http://Y%20Combinator)

For factorial it is like

```js
var Y = (proc) => {
  return ((x) => {
    return proc((y) => { return (x(x))(y);});
  })((x) => {
    return proc((y) => { return (x(x))(y);});
  });
};

var factorial = (fact) => {
 return (n) => {
  return (n === 0) ? 1 : n * fact(n-1);
 };
};


console.log( Y(factorial)(5) );
```

For you code it will be like

```
const fn = (func)=> {

    return (parameter) => {
       // if else
       func(X);
    }
};

Y(fn)(0);
```

Comment: This may be true, but this isn't self invoked. I'd like to remove the `Y(fn)(0);`. This solution seems to be a more complex but with the same result like mine.