# Is there a difference between IIFEs defined by arrow notation and regular function declaration?

Tags: javascript, iife

I know the differences between functions defined by arrow notation vs older/regular function declaration as laid out nicely in this post: [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch).

Namely:

1. Arrow functions bind `this` to parent execution context implicitly
2. Arrow functions cannot be used as constructors
3. You can't name function expressions using arrow syntax
4. Some other things such as using `arguments` (that I didn't know existed anyway)

In practical terms, is there any difference between using arrow function syntax / older function syntax for IIFEs? i.e.:

```
(function(context) {...})(this);
```

VS

```
((context) => {...})(this);
```

It doesn't seem like there are...

Also. As mentioned in an answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38951021/3114742, there is mention that IIFEs are bad practice. But I quite like them... Is there a legitimate reason to avoid them?

Comment: It seems to me you are overly sensitive and are trying to do right by everybody. Your quoted Medium article merely states, that the block constructs and `let` variable assignments of ES6 can be used instead of IIFE. But it does not condemn them to be "bad".

Comment: I would consider IIFE a good practice when following functional paradigms, otherwise it might be confusing to a teammate not coming from a js background. And you already listed all of the differences and none of them applies to your snippet so dont you know the answer yourself?

Comment: Regarding "*IIFEs are bad practice*", the [answer you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38951021/3114742) makes an unsupported statement. The [article referenced](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/5-javascript-bad-parts-that-are-fixed-in-es6-c7c45d44fd81) simply points out that ECMAScript 2015 features can be used as an alternative, not that IIFEs are "bad practice".

Comment: Yes @JonasW. - assuming my understanding of JavaScript in this regard is correct, then I do know the answer. But it's this understanding that I'm checking...