# Why can't an IIFE be used with Douglas Crockford's style when I rewrite it with an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, iife

I have an IIFE that works, but when I rewrite it using an arrow function, it does not work!

1.- This one works fine:

```
let j = 3;

(function (n) {
  while (n--)
    console.log("n only", n);
}(j));
```

2.- This one doesn't work!:

```
((n) => {
  while (n--)
    console.log("n only", n);
}(j));
```

3.- I have already tested the next version which works too:

```
((n) => {
  while (n--)
    console.log("n only", n);
})(j);
```

But I really want to understant why the version on (2) does not work.

Comment: Looks like the arrow function needs to be surrounded in `()`s to be fully parsed as an expression first, or something of the sort, while `function`s don't

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589488/es6-immediately-invoked-arrow-function

Comment: @CertainPerformance, was a little typo in nº1, it was corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how the language defined it. As [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Parsing_order) states:

> Although the arrow in an arrow function is not an operator, arrow functions have special parsing rules that interact differently with operator precedence compared to regular functions.

It continues to give another example, but the principle is the same:

> ```
> let callback;
>
> callback = callback || function() {}; // ok
>
> callback = callback || () => {};
> // SyntaxError: invalid arrow-function arguments
>
> callback = callback || (() => {});    // ok
> ```

Although Crockford expressed a preference for putting the closing parenthesis of an IIFE at the very end (after the arguments), I personally find it more intuitive to put it at the same place as where it is required for arrow functions (after the closing brace, before the arguments).

The reason is that the purpose of the parentheses is to turn a *function* into a function expression and so the arguments really aren't significant in that conversion. So this seems just more to the point:

```
(function (n) => {
  while (n--)
    console.log("n only", n);
})(j);
```

Comment: I also prefer using parenthesis enclosing the functions before the arguments, gives more sense from a mathematical point of view. If I had followed this preference from the beginning I would never have encountered this problem.

Answer (score 1):

What is and what isn't valid syntax is determined by the language [grammar](http://MemberExpression[?Yield,%20?Await]Arguments).

A `CallExpression` is defined as

```
MemberExpression Arguments
```

But an `ArrowFunction` is not a `MemberExpression`, it's an `AssignmentExpression`.

*Why* that's the case would be a question for the TC39 committee.

Comment: The grammar for arrow function compared to function looks a little messy. The documentation on mdn says that  "[...] the arrow in an arrow function is not an operator", and at the same time, an arrow function is an AssignmentExpression!!??

Comment: That’s actually OK. Don’t confuse “AssignmentExpression” with an actual assignment. It’s just a non-terminal symbol that describes rules about the language. Every expression is basically an “AssingmentExpression”. If you think of the grammar describing a tree, AssignmentExpression sits almost at the top. `5` is also an AssignmentExpression.

Answer (score -1):

Both work, but you made a typo: make sure you write `(<function def>)()`

```js
let a = 3;

((b) => {
  while(b--) console.log(b);
})(a);

(function(b){
  while(b--) console.log(b);
})(a);
```

Comment: Pretty sure the inconsistency OP is asking about is that the `function` does *not* need to be surrounded in `()`s, while the arrow function *does*.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.

Comment: In my defense, the question is a bit unclear... I didn't downvoted, but the content of [this](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) reflects my reaction to the question

Comment: There are many ways to ask a question. In this case, I could ask about the inconsistency that CertainPerformance refers to