# How to get the result of setTimeout function?

Tags: javascript

problem code is :

```
var result = 10;
function wait(time,f) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  result = f(result);
  }, time);
}

wait(500, function(x) {return x + 5})
wait(250, function(x) {return x * 2})
```

I think what the result is 30, but result is 25(solution).

Why the result value is 25?

Comment: result becomes 20 then becomes 25 based on the timing of the function calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You schedule two callbacks:

```
wait(500, function(x) {return x + 5}) // execute after 500ms
wait(250, function(x) {return x * 2}) // execute after 250ms
```

The first argument is the time after which the callback will be run. Since the second `wait` call has the lower first argument, it runs first.

At 250ms or so, since `result` starts at 10, the `x * 2` multiplies `result` by 2, getting you to 20.

Then, at 500ms or so, the `x + 5` runs, getting you to 25.

If you want to be able to do this sort of thing such that the code appears to run more sequentially, use Promises and `await` instead:

```js
let result = 10;
function wait(time,f) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    result = f(result);
    resolve();
  }, time));
}

(async () => {
  await wait(250, x => x * 2);
  await wait(250, x => x + 5);
  console.log(result);
})();
```

Comment: I find it strange that some parsers will not allow `(function(){})()`, only accepting `(function(){}())`, while they only accept `(()=>{})()`, not `(()=>{}())`. Any idea why, @CertainPerformance?

Comment: All modern parsers *should* behave identically in such situations - that sort of fundamental syntax is clearly defined in the specification. Still, `(function(){})()` should work just fine (do you have an example link where it appears not to?). `(function(){}())` should always work too. `(()=>{}())` will not, because [*an ArrowFunction cannot be on the LHS of a CallExpression*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34589765).

Comment: I can't remember what Browser, but I did actually have an issue where I had to change `(function(){})()` to `(function(){}())` years ago. I was baffled at the time. I thought it to be a Browser bug, but still had the issue, so I just changed my code, then it worked. I actually prefer the parameters on the outside. Made more sense to me. I'll forget 
I ever had the issue, now, but I actually did in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a backward compatible way to achieve what you want, if you want below Edge 15:

```js
const delay = (()=>{
  let n = 0;
  return (time, func)=>{
    n += time; setTimeout(func, n);
    return delay;
  }
})();
let x = 10;
delay(500, ()=>{
  x += 5;
  console.log(x);
})(250, ()=>{
  x *= 2;
  console.log(x);
});
```