# '}' Expected in React Component Render Method (Using JSX)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm getting an error message 'Expecting '}'' just before calling the Function Expression in code given below.

```js
class IfElse extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {
                    (booleanExp)=>{
                        return(
                        <a href={(booleanExp)?'login':'logout'}>{(booleanExp)?'login':'logout'}</a>
                        )
                    }(this.props.booleanExp)
                }
            </div>
            
        )
    }
};
```

The error is here: `}(this.props.booleanExp)`, just after the curly brace. If i remove the function invocation, then there is no error But function call is required for me.

Comment: What is your point of adding this round brackets?

Comment: I think you are asking about the ones after the `return`. They are just to avoid any unexpected syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the function in `(` and `)`.

E.g:

```js
((booleanExp)=>{
    return(
        <a href={(booleanExp)?'login':'logout'}>{(booleanExp)?'login':'logout'}</a>
    )
})(this.props.booleanExp)
```

Comment: Yes that worked! I really appreciate your contribution. I'll request you to explain the problem and why the brackets solved them, if you like, otherwise you have the upvote.

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589488/es6-immediately-invoked-arrow-function)

Answer (score 0):

```
class IfElse extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          (booleanExp) => (
            <a href={(booleanExp) ? 'login' : 'logout'}>{(booleanExp) ? 'login' : 'logout'}</a>
          )(this.props.booleanExp)
        }
      </div>

    )
  }
};
```

Comment: Nope! it Doesn't work. Its just the simple JavaScript Inline undefined kind of function and I'm sure that only curly braces are used for the body.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to invoke a function inside of render method? Can you simply use ternary expression:

```
class IfElse extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <a href={this.props.booleanExp ? 'login' : 'logout'}> 
                  {this.props.booleanExp ? 'login' : 'logout'}
                </a>
            </div>
            
        )
    }
};
```

or even simplify it to a functional component:

```
const IfElse = ({booleanExp}) => (
 <div>
   <a href={booleanExp ? 'login' : 'logout'}> 
     {booleanExp ? 'login' : 'logout'}
   </a>
 </div>
);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your contribution but as I said, function call is required for me. I'm just learning React, that's why.