# JavaScript miss context of self variable

Tags: javascript

Here is mystic behavior of JavaScript. Does it my mistake of usage or some bug?

**JavaScript code**

```
function test(){

  var self = this;

  self.func1 = function(){
    debugger; // here self == Window
  }
  debugger; //here self == test func
  self.func1(); 
}

var t = new test();
```

I provided JSfiddle that you can try it by yourself:

https://jsfiddle.net/stanislavmachel/f44zbvvr/8/

Could somebody explain why context of self variable miss after call?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, you're just reading the debugger wrong.

The JS engine notices that the function `func1` doesn't use the variable `self` so as an optimization measure it [doesn't include it in the context object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388530/why-does-chrome-debugger-think-closed-local-variable-is-undefined). What you see in the debugger is the [global `self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self).

If you use the `self` variable inside the function, e.g. `console.log(self)`, you'll also see it in the debugger's closure list. See https://jsfiddle.net/f44zbvvr/9/.