# Imported functions are not in scope within Firefox debugging console

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a project in React and I'm importing functions from lodash and Immutable.js.

`import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual`

`const {List, Set, Map, is} = require('immutable')`

When I'm debugging my code these functions work in the script but if I stop at a breakpoint and attempt to use them in Firefox's debugging console, I get a ReferenceError telling me they are not defined.

Do I need to explicitly import them in the console? Or am I importing them incorrectly?

Comment: variables in modules are not in the global scope - so, not accessible from console

Comment: So there's no way for me to debug with imported functions?

Comment: I would've thought if the breakpoint was in the module you'd be able to access the currently scoped variables - you haven't made it clear where your breakpoint is

Comment: simplest way is to add what you want to window `window.isEqual = isEqual`

Comment: @JaromandaX they're likely named something different than what's imported. it's possible to explore the vars in scope but that's annoying in my opinion. since it's for testing only, putting things on global scope is quick and easy

Comment: `they're likely named something different` - unlikely

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use **Webpack** to build your source files.

Once you are development mode please set your `NODE_ENV` to `development`.

You can also add `mode: 'development'` into your webpack.config.js file.

After you can use `debugger;` in anywhere in your code and when you run your code in the browser you can debug from that line.

For further reading: https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-source-maps

Answer (score 0):

The variable names are not preserved during transpilation/minification/uglification process. Therefore you have to look for the changed variable name, to access them in the console.

You can find an in detail approach how to find out the real variable name [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66190247/4316681)