# Accessing closure variables in the console

Tags: google-chrome

Given this code

```
function foo()
{
    var x = 1;

    function bar()
    {
        debugger;
        return x + 1;
    }

    return bar();
}
```

when I open the Google Chrome's console and and `foo()` gets executed, the console stops at the `debugger` line. If I type 'x' in the console, I get **Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined**.

If I want to access `x` in the console, I have two options:

- Under *Source* go to *Scope*, open *Closure*, make a right click on `x` and click *Store as Global Variable*. This will create a global variable `temp1` with which I can access `x`.
- edit `bar` to

  ```
  function var()
  {
      x;
      debugger;
      return x + 1;
  }
  ```

I noticed that when you put a `debugger` and the code accessed a scope variable at some point, then I can access it in the console.

I found other threads [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388530/why-does-chrome-debugger-think-closed-local-variable-is-undefined) more or less aksing the same question. Is there a better way to access the closure variables?

Btw I use `Version 59.0.3071.104 (Official Build) (64-bit)` for Debian 8.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you already got the answer in the [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388530/why-does-chrome-debugger-think-closed-local-variable-is-undefined) you referred to. @OwnageIsMagic said it was because of V8 optimization. If you click the function name in the Call Stack, that variable will be accessible then.