# "arguments" variable in JavaScript arrow functions not debuggable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools, arrow-functions

I was reading this on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

In a section titled "No binding of arguments" I saw the following and tried it on the browser console. Works.

> #### No binding of arguments
>
> Arrow functions do not have their own arguments object. Thus, in this example, > arguments is simply a reference to the the arguments of the enclosing scope:

When I tried to debug the arrow function, the value of arguments is different and unexpected. Is this a bug in DevTools or am I overlooking something?

In the example below, `arguments.length` printed in the console is 1. (The value being 1)

However, when execution stops at a breakpoint, `arguments.length` is 4. (The values being 1, 6, 7, 8)

```
(function() {

    var obj = {
        fn: function(a) {
            var f = v=> { 
                debugger; 
                console.log("Arguments length " + arguments.length);
            };
            return f(a, 6, 7, 8);
        }
    };
    obj.fn(1);
}
)();
```

jsFiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/3Lb640aq/

Comment: Also weird: in the console, `this` evaluates to `undefined` (in strict mode) at the breakpoint and is shown in the scope inspector, but logging it yields `obj` (as expected).

Comment: Are you using Babel, or native ES6? Seeing `4` in the debugger does indeed seem like a bug.

Comment: @loganfsmyth native ES6. Chrome and Firefox both have this behavior.

Comment: @Bergi where did you put the "use strict"? Line 2 or 5 or 6? I'm not able to repro what you said. Could you please update the fiddle if and when you have time?

Comment: @xadhix Line 2, in the outer IIFE

Comment: @Bergi I updated the https://jsfiddle.net/3Lb640aq/2/ with a `console.log(this);`  

I get the same value while debugging and logging. What am I missing?  

Maybe if logged and debugged at the same time, it wouldn't happen. Maybe related to this awesome bug/optimization from V8 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388530/why-does-chrome-debugger-think-closed-local-variable-is-undefined  

screenshot : https://imgur.com/a/9R1VP

Comment: @xadhix Right, it does work when evaluating `this` in the console, but the [scope pane](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#scope) shows `undefined`

Comment: Chrome's debugger has always been a bit wonky with regard to evaluating things that aren't used in the current immediate scope. A few more observations: If I run this code as-is in sloppy mode, the Scope pane says that `this` is Window, but if I enter `this` in the console and hit Enter, it says `undefined`. If I add `this;` after the `console.log` line and repeat the above, the Scope pane continues to say that `this` is Window, but if I enter `this` in the console and hit Enter, it correctly logs a representation of `obj`.

Comment: I'd say the moral of the story is, (1) don't trust the Chrome debugger regarding anything that's not utilized in the current immediate scope unless you're evaluating it w.r.t. some global variable (`window.something.somethingElse`) and (2) `arguments` is unreliable even if it's used in the current immediate scope.

Comment: @Bergi Got it. Thanks for pointing it out.