# GWT 2.5.1 + source maps (Super dev mode) - local variable evaluation

Tags: gwt, source-maps

Trying to use Super Dev mode with a GWT 2.1.5 project.
I have configured Super dev mode (it works) I can see the sources in Javascript debugger, can use breakpoints, however I cannot evaluate variables at execution time.
Is there any trick to have Google Chrome's javascript debugger not trip on local variables evaluation ? Do I need to find another name for the variable (the actual name of the variable, not the name that is in the sources ?) for evaluation ?
See below.
[image: screencap]

edit: actually I think I have  found part of the answer in GWT's official page. "When inspecting variables in the Chrome debugger, the field names and values are JavaScript, not Java.". I have no idea where those names can be seen, though, any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be related to this question [Why does Chrome debugger think closed local variable is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388530/why-does-chrome-debugger-think-closed-local-variable-is-undefined)

It is incredibly annoying for debugging purposes though, and any means to circumvent it would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try switching off obfuscation? This is described in this document [FAQ - Debugging and Compiling - Why is my GWT-generated JavaScript gibberish?](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html). You could try the compiler parameters -style PRETTY or -style DETAILED

Also: the SDBG project allows source map debugging within the Eclipse IDE. There is a GitHub bug report on the issue you describe. It might help you: [Add support for mapping field names](https://sdbg.github.io).