# function statement's strange behavior when inspecting node.js in chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools

I use chrome devtools to debug node.js script (`node --inspect script.js`, as described e.g. in
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/)

For some reason a function statement is not working properly. This is the code:

```
function f(){};
f=1;
console.log(f);

http = require('http');
myserver=http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

The console outputs `1`, but then when I try to enter `f` in the console it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: f is not defined".

If instead of a function statement I use function expression, everything works well:

```
f=function(){};
f=1;
console.log(f);

http = require('http');
myserver=http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

So I wonder what is the source of the problem and how to fix it.

P.S. The createServer part of the script is a trick I use so that the chrome devtools console is still running after the script has been executed. By the way, is there any more straightforward way to do it?

Update:
I stumbled upon an alternative way which does not have this problem with function statement:
`node --inspect -e "$(< script.js)"`

Comment: `setInterval(() => 0, 10000)`

Comment: Thanks. By the way: `node -i -e "$(< script.js)"` works well (runs a script without a problem with function statement and opens a node repl (right in the terminal)) even without this setInterval/createServer trick. `node --inspect -e "$(< script.js)"` works well in the chrome devtools console, but still requires a setInterval/createServer trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first script declares are local variable in the module scope, which is initialised with the function, then assigned with `1`, then garbage collected - the server closure doesn't use it, see [Why does Chrome debugger think closed local variable is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388530/why-does-chrome-debugger-think-closed-local-variable-is-undefined).

The second script does not declare any variable<sup>1</sup>, it does assign to a global<sup>2</sup>. First the function, then the value `1`, but global variables cannot get garbage-collected as any code that runs later might still access them.

<sub>[1]: Using `var f` would probably lead the the same result as with the first script.
[2]: Always [`"use strict"` mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)! You would have gotten a proper exception.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! Could you check your second link: it is the same as your first link.

Comment: @GrigoryHatsevich Thanks, fixed. That happens when I fat-finger Ctrl+C :-/