# Why are my watch expressions (unavailable) in Firefox debugger?

Tags: firefox, javascript-debugger

I'm trying to debug with Firefox 59.0.2. I'm inside a function and most of my watch expressions are "(unavailable)".  They have values that sometimes display in the scope tab and will display if I use alert() to echo them to the screen.

What is causing this problem?  Is there a scope issue?  I think the global scope variables aren't having this issue.

I am not getting any javascript errors in console.

Comment: According to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1446684 a similar issue was fixed after Firefox 61.

Answer (score -1):

This is often because you're pausing the debugger at a different point in the call stack than where the variable is in scope.  [Here's a potential clue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388530/why-does-chrome-debugger-think-closed-local-variable-is-undefined)

Comment: That's not always the case. It became like that just recently, and it's annoying!