# Why isn't Firefox debugger showing the value of my variables?

Tags: debugging, firefox

Shouldn't Firefox debugger give me the value of a variable that is going to be used in the current line? Why isn't it?

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, both `paisH` and `lat0` (global variables) are going to be used right now to calculate `lat`. Then why aren't they available at the `Watch expressions` window?

I'm using Firefox Quantum 60.8.0esr (64-bit) on Debian 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without details, this is a duplicate of [Why are my watch expressions (unavailable) in Firefox debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125252/why-are-my-watch-expressions-unavailable-in-firefox-debugger)

I see you're using an old version of Firefox and in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1446684 someone notes that a similar problem was fixed after Firefox 61.

Comment: The linked question seems to be about scope (though there's no accepted answer). In my question the variables are global.