# Why aren't my function's variables available in my promise's callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, callback, react-redux

I have the following function. What I'm trying to undestand is, why wouldn't all four variables in the `apiCall` function be available to the promise resolution via `then`? Is there a way to access `var1`, `var2` and `var3` inside the `then` callback? Am I misunderstanding Javascript scope or is there something else in my code that could be the culprit?

```
apiCall (addOrRemove, var1, var2, var3) {
  debugger;  // ALL VARIABLES addOrRemove, var1, var2 and var3 ARE DEFINED HERE
  if (addOrRemove === 'add') {
    let reduxArray = this.state.reduxArray
    reduxArray.push({
      var1: var1,
      var2: var2
    })
    this.setState({
      reduxArray: reduxArray
    })
    this.props.dispatch(actionCreator(var1, var2))
    .then((response) => {
      debugger;  // ONLY var1 IS DEFINED HERE
    })
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Are you saying this based solely on what you see in the debugger? Or have you actually tried `console.log(var2)`?

Comment: Does this happen in v8? It may be one of its optimizations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28431346/1651698

Comment: *"Am I misunderstanding Javascript scope"*... probably. And probably misunderstanding debugger context also

Comment: @deceze you are exactly right. Do you know what on earth is going on?

Comment: Don't rely too much on debuggers is the lesson, I guess.

Comment: @YPCrumble Have you checked the link I posted? It might be really just an optimization. If you used the variable near the debugger statement it would work as you expected.

Comment: @Razem that's exactly the problem - thank you.