# top-level module variables unreachable when debugging in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, debugging, ecmascript-6, module

while playing with native modules in Chrome browser (a module is a `script` with `type` set to `module`) I've found a strange behavior. Having this code:

```
var a = 1;
let b = 2;
const c = 3;
debugger;
console.log(a, b, c);
```

There were no variables in local scope, but clearly there are (`a`, `b`, and `c`) as they are logged in the console.

[image]

Interestingly, adding a function that uses top-level variables makes them appear in the Scope panel:

```
var a = 1;
let b = 2;
const c = 3;
debugger;
function f() {
  console.log(a, b, c);
}
f();
```

[image]

Why is it like that?

Comment: Constant folding perhaps? Chrome is able to do [strange optimisations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388530/why-does-chrome-debugger-think-closed-local-variable-is-undefined)