# Why can't I access the xhr object from inside my onreadystatechange handler?

Tags: javascript, scope, xmlhttprequest

**Edit:** I have removed the original code and replaced it with generalized code that anyone can run themselves to reproduce my problem:

```
var StripeCheckout = {
    configure: function(obj){
        obj.token();
    }
};

StripeCheckout.configure({
    token: function(token) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/process-order');
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            debugger; // right here is the problem
        };
        request.send();
    }
});
```

For me, inside that anonymous function where the `debugger` statement is, `request` is mysteriously not defined and attempting to access it is a `ReferenceError`. That really mystifies me.

This is the weird part. If I create a throwaway variable defined at the top level, and set `throwaway = request;` right after creating the `request` object, then inside the `onreadystatechange` handler `throwaway` is defined and everything is okay, even though `request` is not defined.

I just tested it, and I can also access it as `this` at the point of the debugger statement, as expected. What gives? Why is `request` not defined?

Comment: What happens if you replace `debugger;` with `console.log(response);`?

Comment: Dont always trust debuggers. Trust what you know of the language. I've seen plenty of cases where for instance, the Edge debugger would lie about state.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Why does Chrome debugger think closed local variable is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28388530/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript functions are *closures*. They capture the variables in the surrounding scope that they need in order to work, but no more. Since you are not referencing `request` in the actual code of your function, it is not captured by JavaScript because your function doesn't appear to need it. If you include code that references `request`, then it will be defined:

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/process-order');
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(request.toString());
    debugger;
};
request.send();
```

If you run this snippet with your browser's developer tools window open, it will stop on the `debugger` statement, and `request` will be defined.

[image]

On the other hand, your original snippet may fail because `request` is not referenced in the function, so the closure does not include it. By the time you try to look at the value of `request`, it may have already been cleaned up.

The reason that this happens is for performance: if JavaScript functions just captured every single variable in scope, then many variables would never be released, and your web browser would use even *more* memory and take a performance hit due to having to keep track of all of those variables for longer.

Answer (score 1):

The reference to `request` is a reference into the execution context surrounding the inner function, which is a heap-allocated structure implementing part of the closure, and is subject to garbage collection.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28431346/712765), the V8 JavaScript engine (which is used by Chrome and Node.JS, among other applications, to implement JavaScript) does not create a closure if there is no reference to it. (This is an optimization.) Therefore, by the time you hit the debugger, the reference to `request` has been lost, which is why you get `ReferenceError` rather than `undefined`. Note that the behavior is different in Safari 11, which uses JavaScriptCore from WebKit (rather than V8) to implement JavaScript.

If you add a reference to `request` inside the inner function, then the closure will be created by V8 and you will have access to in inside the debugger.

### Examples

Run this code in Chrome (or as I have, in Opera, which also uses V8) and you will see a Closure listed in the Scope chain.

```js
var StripeCheckout = {
  configure: function(obj) {
    return obj.token();
  }
};

StripeCheckout.configure({
  token: function(token) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      // include the console.log statement 
      // and everything works as expected.
      console.log('req.rs:', request.readyState);
      debugger; // right here is the problem
    };
    request.send();
  }
});
```

[image: Chrome debugger showing closure]

Comment out the `console.log` statement, which is the only reference to the closure, and the closure itself disappears (with V8).

[image: Closure not present with V8]

However, when you run the same code (without the reference) in Safari, which uses JavaScriptCore from WebKit instead of V8, and the closure is still present with `request` defined, and the debugger works as expected.

[image: Closure present in Safari]