# How can I turn off Chrome v8 javascript engine optimization when debugging web application?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, v8

I came across well known problem when debugging javascript in Chrome browser, described in this question [Why does Chrome debugger think closed local variable is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388530/why-does-chrome-debugger-think-closed-local-variable-is-undefined)

The problem described there seems to be caused by the optimization done by v8 engine in Chrome. The workaround mentioned there is not very user (programmer) friendly.

So I was wondering is there some way to completely turn off v8 optimization in Chrome devtools when debugging javascript in my web application?

Comment: If you run Chrome with the `--allow-natives-syntax` there is a function called -> `%NeverOptimizeFunction()`, only problem here is if you then run without the flag your app will fail.  So to make this easier you might also like this npm module ->  https://www.npmjs.com/package/v8-natives

Comment: Why do you need to debug variables that are no longer used anywhere?

Comment: No, there is no checkbox to disable optimisation.