# When debugging a reducer in the browser, why can't I see a variable's value?

Tags: javascript, redux, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps, firefox-developer-tools

When using the Chrome or Firefox developer tools, I cannot peer into the values of certain reducer variables. For example, the `newItem` in the Chrome debugger screenshot below:

Chrome:
[image: Chrome screenshot]

Firefox:
[image: Firefox screenshot]

The code runs fine. Log statements output correctly, but inspecting via the debugger just shows `undefined`. However, if I look in the Scope view, I can see a variable called `_newItem` that has all the correct properties and values (obscured because they are potentially sensitive).

What seems to cause this issue is when I do a shallow clone of the state: `let newState = {...state};` (either with spread syntax or `Object.assign({}, state)`.

Every subsequent variable based on `newState` shows `undefined` but has a corresponding `_variableName[0-9]*` on the dev tools Scope view.

This does not happen in our React components, or other non-Reducer code.

It seems it could be some issue with Redux, source maps and the developer tools, but I cannot find anything searching either the Redux documentation or issue tracker, nor the Chrome bug tracker.

Redux: `4.0.5`
OS: Windows 10 x64

Tested on:
Chrome: `81.0.4044.122`, Canary: `84.0.4125.0`
Firefox: `75.0`, Dev. Edition: `76.0b4 (64-bit)`

Note: This is not the same as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388530/why-does-chrome-debugger-think-closed-local-variable-is-undefined) that deals with just Chrome's optimizations of closure variables.

Comment: Does this also happen when you pause on the line below: `group.items = [`? Sometimes Chrome doesn't map variables properly in certain scopes. Also in the debugger the variable `_newItem` is prefixed with `_`, whereas in your source it has no `_` so it's not the same variable right?

Comment: @BenWinding Yes, it happens regardless of where the breakpoint or current execution line is. And, in the variables in the scope pane with `_` are the same. It's just that there can be many such variables. See the ones with the `_group` prefix. `_group3` has the correct values that should be shown for `group` in the source view. It always seems to be the last one, the others seem to always be undefined. It's like there's a source-map issue but it's an ejected `create-react-app` with no build modifications.

Comment: _"It's just that there can be many such variables."_ So is the variable without the`_` prefix in one of the scope panes too? Also, are you able to view the value by typing it into the Chrome console? And finally, does this issue show up using Firefox dev tools aswell?

Comment: @BenWinding I just checked, the console mirrors what the scope pane has. That is, they are "mangled" there as well.

Comment: @BenWinding If the variable name has been "mangled" with an underscore, the unmangled form exists but is `undefined`. It happens with both the Chrome and Firefox dev tools. I updated the question with a FF screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

To see the values of the reducers I usually use the `Redux DevTools Extension` plugin that way it looks great and allows me to debug every state change.

If you want to see the documentation here I leave it to you:
[Redux DevTools Extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension)