# React app - disparity between debugger and console log

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've had this issue pop up in one form or another over the years, and I finally figured out how to put it to words. Consider the following code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import aFunction from "./Function";

export default class SomeComponent extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    console.log(aFunction);
    debugger;
    return(
      <div>some stuff</div>
    )
  }
}
```

The console.log() call will print information about aFunction, but if I type "aFunction" into the browser console I get a reference error. Why does this happen? Shouldn't console.log and the browser console via debugger have access to the same scope?

EDIT: I should clarify that I'm getting a reference error after allowing the "debugger" to occur before typing "aFunction". I'm not trying to call up block scoped variables after render() has completed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: It didn't quite answer it, but I needed the refresher so it's still really helpful, thanks. After reading that I realized I had forgotten there was a scope difference between var and let/const...

Comment: Well, I thought it'd help explain why `console` is on the `window` object or otherwise in global scope whereas `aFunction` is imported and has more localized scope. You can add `aFunction` to the global object and it'd be accessible in the browser's console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an engine optimisation. Variables are invisible if they are not needed.

You can use a small hack to prevent it.

```
eval('debugger');
```

And when you use console.log you have it in your scope.
So, you can use another hack:

```
const temp = smthFromParentScope;
debugger;
```

It happens when you are in a nested function and there are no functions that have a reference to them.

```
function foo() {
    const a = 1;
    const b = 2;

    function bar() {
        console.log(a); // now we have a ref
    }

    function baz() {
        debugger; // here we can see only 'a'
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh, interesting.. This is helpful, thanks. I think I need a refresher on scope...

Comment: There is a great detailed explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28431346/4186110