# how can I see js garbage collector in action

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

in order to see garbage collection in action.
I want to write a script for chrome enviorment that declares a variable and prints it to the console. and then get collected by garbage collector (- so when I try to access it through dev tools I will get a reference error.
according to this link :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management ,
under Real-life example section -
if I use internet explore 7 and run the script:

```js
var div;

window.onload = function() {
    div = document.getElementById('myDivElement');
};
```

which is the example given in the link above but without the circular reference part.
if I will try to open ie7 console and try to reach div - I would get a reference error ( like I want ) because div would be garbage collected.
how can I do something similar now in chrome?

Comment: Why waste your time with long-dead and deeply-buried browsers?

Comment: @ATP . it dosn't answer my question . as my goal is to write short example of script , in which trying to access a variable after gc would  return a reference error . I tried to manually run the gc from the performance tab , on the script that was written in my question but I stiil have reference to div .

Comment: "*trying to access a variable after gc would return a reference error*" - actually no, that's not how garbage collection works. If the variable is still accessible, it won't get collected.

Comment: @bergi  . Is it possible to  write a sample script  code , in html file , that when I open with chrom dev tools and trying to access a variable from the script   I would get reference error since the variable was cleaned ? since the script has no further references to the variable ?

Comment: No, that is not really possible. If the script is trying to access the variable, it won't be collected. (Unless you mean something like [attempting to access variables with the debugger that have been optimised away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388530/why-does-chrome-debugger-think-closed-local-variable-is-undefined))