# Implementing the IAsyncContentCreation interface in UI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

To ensure [`sap.ui.core.UIComponent`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.UIComponent) to be created fully asynchronously, we need to implement the [`IAsyncContentCreation`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.IAsyncContentCreation) interface:

```js
metadata: {
    interfaces: [
        "sap.ui.core.IAsyncContentCreation"
    ],
    manifest: "json"
}
```

That's totally OK.
Exploring the SAP apps samples, I've found out the following code snippet, where the hard-coded and, thus error prone, interface name is replaced with code, which can be automatically checked:

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/library",
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    …
], function(library, UIComponent, models, History) {
    "use strict";

    return UIComponent.extend("sap.ui.demo.toolpageapp.Component", {

        metadata: {
            interfaces: [
                library.IAsyncContentCreation
            ],
            manifest: "json"
        }
        …

    }
}
```

I've tried to check the content of `library` in DevTools, but I get a `ReferenceError` exception instead of the `library`'s values:

```js
Uncaught ReferenceError: library is not defined
    at eval (eval at init (Component.js:24), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at f.init (Component.js:24)
    at sap-ui-core.js:315
    at f.constructor (sap-ui-core.js:315)
    at f.constructor (sap-ui-core.js:585)
    at f.constructor (library-preload.js:1154)
    at f [as constructor] (sap-ui-core.js:547)
    at new o1 (sap-ui-core.js:632)
    at H (sap-ui-core.js:628)
    at sap-ui-core.js:628
```

How can I ensure that [`library.IAsyncContentCreation`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/library.js) is really properly defined and returns `"sap.ui.core.IAsyncContentCreation"` as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've tried to check the content of `library` in DevTools, but I get a `ReferenceError` exception.

Most probably, you've encountered the V8's debugger limitation, where the unused closure variables (here: `library`) are not evaluated by the V8 during the debugger session, and thus not accessible from the devtool console. See [Why does Chrome debugger think closed local variable is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388530/why-does-chrome-debugger-think-closed-local-variable-is-undefined)  and also the V8 issues [#`3491`](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3491) and [#`2710`](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2710).

The above limitation applies only to V8's debugger. When the code is executed at runtime, `library.IAsyncContentCreation` will be resolved to the string `"sap.ui.core.IAsyncContentCreation"` as expected so you won't get the `ReferenceError`.

> Exploring the SAP apps samples, [...] interface name is replaced with code.

It's unclear why the sample author decided to require the core library in the first place. Those [`interfaces` in UI5 Objects](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.Object#methods/sap.ui.base.Object.extend) await **string literals.** And UI5 interfaces are simple marker interfaces (aka. tagging interfaces). They don't specify any behavior in code. Adding the interface name (string literal) simply tells how the class implementing the interface is supposed to behave. So adding the string literal is sufficient.

```js
interfaces: [
  "sap.ui.core.IAsyncContentCreation"
],
```

Comment: Thx for clarification!, I assume the main idea behind `library.IAsyncContentCreation` vs. `"sap.ui.core.IAsyncContentCreation"` is just to avoid the hard coded strings, which are typo error prone. The main question, does requiring the core library `sap.ui.core.library` significantly impacts the performance?

Comment: BTW, `console.log(library.IAsyncContentCreation);` prints `sap.ui.core.IAsyncContentCreation`.

Comment: @Mike _> does requiring the core library [...] significantly impact the performance?_ ...
I wouldn't say so because requiring `sap/ui/core/library` is not the same as actually loading the entire library bundle. Still, I'd consider **not** to require an additional module if I could replace it with a single string literal in the `interfaces` section (personal preference). Generally, I focus on UX rather than DX in such cases. But of course, it would be nice if writing `"sap.ui.core.IAsyncCont..."` could be auto-completed. I wonder if TypeScript could help