# How can I prevent a DOM node removed from its tree from being held by spurious strong references, like from closures?

Tags: javascript, dom, closures, weak-references

For a toy example, suppose I have a clock widget:

```js
{
  const clockElem = document.getElementById('clock');

  const timefmt = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
    'default', { timeStyle: 'medium', });

  setInterval(() => {
    const d = new Date;
    console.log('tick', d, clockElem);
    clockElem.querySelector('p').innerHTML =
      timefmt.format(d);
  }, 1000);

  clockElem.querySelector('button')
    .addEventListener('click', ev => {
      clockElem.remove();
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="clock">
  <button>Remove</button>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

When I click the button to remove the clock, the `setInterval` callback is still invoked.  The callback closure holds the DOM node strongly, which means its resources cannot be freed.  There is also the circular reference from the button event handler; though perhaps that one could be handled by the engine’s cycle collector.  Then again, maybe not.

Never fear: I can create a helper function ensuring that closures only hold the DOM node by a weak reference, and throw in `FinalizationRegistry` to clean up the timer.

```js
const weakCapture = (captures, func) => {
  captures = captures.map(o => new WeakRef(o));
  return (...args) => {
    const objs = [];
    for (const wr of captures) {
      const o = wr.deref();
      if (o === void 0)
        return;
      objs.push(o);
    }
    return func(objs, ...args);
  }
};

const finregTimer = new FinalizationRegistry(
  timerId => clearInterval(timerId));

{
  let clockElem = document.getElementById('clock');

  const timefmt = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
    'default', { timeStyle: 'medium', });

  const timerId = setInterval(
    weakCapture([clockElem], ([clockElem]) => {
      const d = new Date;
      console.log('tick', d);
      clockElem.querySelector('p').innerHTML =
        timefmt.format(d);
    }), 1000);
  
  finregTimer.register(clockElem, timerId);

  clockElem.querySelector('button')
    .addEventListener('click',
      weakCapture([clockElem], ([clockElem], ev) => {
        clockElem.remove();
      }));

  clockElem = null;

  // now clockElem should be held strongly only by the DOM
}
```

```html
<div id="clock">
  <button>Remove</button>
  <p></p>
</div>
<button onclick="+'9'.repeat(1e9)">Try to force GC</button>
```

But this doesn’t seem to work.  Even after the `clockElem` node is removed, the ‘tick’ keeps being logged to the console, meaning the `WeakRef` has not been emptied, meaning something seems to still hold a strong reference to `clockElem`.  Given that GC is not guaranteed to run immediately, I expected some delay, of course, but even when I try to force GC by running memory-heavy code like `+'9'.repeat(1e9)` in the console, the weak reference is not cleared (despite this being enough to force GC and clear weak references in even more trivial cases like `new WeakRef({})`).  This happens both in Chromium (118.0.5993.117) and in Firefox (115.3.0esr).

Is this a flaw in the browsers?  Or is there perhaps some other strong reference that I missed?

(In short: this is an attempt to implement the [weak event pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/events/weak-event-patterns) in JavaScript.)

Comment: Actually your code seems to work for me, it does stop the interval with the logging when I hit the "collect rubbish" button in the Chrome devtools after the "Remove" button

Comment: I have a feeling that this might also depend on the optimisation level. Notice that you still create a closure over `timefmt` which is declared in the same scope as `clockElem`, and you might not be able to rely on [this optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28388530/1048572). You could try `weakCapture([clockElem, timefmt], ([clockElem, timefmt]) => {` or also setting `clockElem = null` at the end of the function (with `let`).

Comment: I think I did try the latter, in a private copy of this example. It didn’t seem to make a difference.

Comment: "*I tried to force GC by running memory-heavy code*" - did you actually verify with the profiler that a garbage collection occured?

Comment: I verfied wiith `wr = new WeakRef({}); await +'9'.repeat(1e9); wr.deref()` that *some* garbage collection occurred. I also triggered GC from `about:memory`. No difference.

Answer (score 7):

`[Element].remove()` removes ('disconnects') `Element` *from the DOM*, but not from memory. As long as `setInterval` is not ended, it will keep running happily with the element from memory.

So *ending the timer function* will make the element garbage collectable (if there are no other references to it ofcourse).

You can check the existence of an element *in the DOM* using its [isConnected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected) property and end the timer if it's not connected anymore.

For the clock example something like (changed `setInterval` to a more manageable `setTimeout`).

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ev => 
  ev.target.closest(`#clock`)?.remove());
let timer;
const log = t => document.querySelector(`#log2Screen`).textContent = t;
const clockElem = document.getElementById('clock');
const timefmt = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('default', { timeStyle: 'medium', });

run();

function run() {
  if (!clockElem.isConnected) {
    console.log(
      `div#clock exists in memory:`, 
      clockElem ); 
    // clear timer when #clock not in DOM
    return clearTimeout(timer); 
  }
  const d = timefmt.format(new Date);
  log(`tick ${d}`);
  clockElem.querySelector('p').textContent = d;
  timer = setTimeout(run, 1000);
}
```

```css
#log2Screen {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="clock">
  <button id="remove">Remove</button>
  <p></p>
</div>
<div id="log2Screen"></div>
```

Alternative 1: you can end the timer *when removing the element from DOM* (so on removing `div#clock`).

```js
let timer;
document.addEventListener('click', ev => {
  ev.target.closest(`#clock`)?.remove();
  clearTimeout(timer); // <= clear timer
} );

const log = t => document.querySelector(`#log2Screen`).textContent = t;
const clockElem = document.getElementById('clock');
const timefmt = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('default', { timeStyle: 'medium', });

run();

function run() {
  const d = timefmt.format(new Date);
  log(`tick ${d}`);
  clockElem.querySelector('p').textContent = d;
  timer = setTimeout(run, 1000);
}
```

```css
#log2Screen {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="clock">
  <button id="remove">Remove</button>
  <p></p>
</div>
<div id="log2Screen"></div>
```

Alternative 2: you can position the assignment of the `#clock` element *within the timer function* and only continue the timer if `div#clock` is still connected to the DOM.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ev => {
  ev.target.closest(`#clock`)?.remove();
} );

let [timer, tick] = [, 0];
const log = t => document.querySelector(`#log2Screen`).textContent = t;
const timefmt = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('default', { timeStyle: 'medium', });

run();

function run() {
  const clockEl = document.querySelector('#clock p');
  
  if (clockEl) { // <= only run when #clock in DOM
    log(`tick ${++tick}`);
    clockEl.textContent = timefmt.format(new Date);
    return timer = setTimeout(run, 1000);
  }
  
  clearTimeout(timer);
  log(`Clock deactived on ${timefmt.format(new Date)}`);
}
```

```css
#log2Screen {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="clock">
  <button id="remove">Remove</button>
  <p></p>
</div>
<div id="log2Screen"></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Here the callback used to remove the node the same can be used to clear the interval being it was stored while declaring.

```js
{
  const clockElem = document.getElementById('clock');

  const timefmt = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
    'default', { timeStyle: 'medium', });

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const d = new Date;
    console.log('tick', d, clockElem);
    clockElem.querySelector('p').innerHTML =
    timefmt.format(d);
  }, 1000);

  clockElem.querySelector('button')
    .addEventListener('click', ev => {
      clearInterval(interval);
      clockElem.remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="clock">
  <button>Remove</button>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The question is not when/how to remove the node and clear the interval, but why the weak reference and the `FinalisationRegistry` do not work