# Javascript: function arguments and arguments[]

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I'm a Javascript novice so please excuse the fundamental question.

I'm working my way through 'Professional Javascript For Web Developers' and in Chapter 3, "Understanding Arguments" section, it discusses accessing function arguments with the arguments[] keyword.

One of the examples shows that you can modify the values in arguments[]:

```
function twoNums(num1, num2) {
    arguments[1] = 10;
    console.log(arguments[0] + num2);
}

twoNums(4,8);  output = 14
```

But it goes on to say that "This effect goes only one way: changing the named argument does not result in a change to the corresponding value in arguments."

However, changing the code to:

```
function twoNums(num1, num2) {
    num2 = 10;
    console.log(arguments[0] + arguments[1]);
}

twoNums(4,8);  output = 14
```

results in the same output so the value in 'arguments[1]' is definitely changing.

Is this:

- an error in the book?
- an error in my understanding?
- something that has changed in Javascript since the writing of the book?

Thanks,

Neil

ANSWERED: A combination of answers solved my problem. Thanks everyone.

Comment: sounds like an old book.

Comment: Is this the book? http://www.amazon.com/Professional-JavaScript-Developers-Wrox-Guides/dp/0764579088 It seems a bit old for web dev, 2005... Or is it a later edition? In any case, your example is how it should work.

Comment: It says "Third Edition, 2012" in the preface.

Comment: And yes, the way it's working is the way I'd imagine it would work (from knowledge of other languages) - that's what made me go "Huh? Really?"

Comment: Cool. 3rd edition seems up to date, I'm not sure what the issue in understanding is. Seems like @bfavaretto has interesting answer.

Comment: Either it's an error of book or error of the browser. Some old browser such as IE8 never follow the W3C standard. Your best bet is to believe in what the browser is rendering.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in the book, by the looks of things: if you reassign any of the arguments passed, the `arguments` object will change (both reference the same value).
Perhaps, though, what was meant in the book was this:

```
function f(n1, n2)
{
    arguments[0] = 2;
    console.log(arguments[0] + arguments[1]);
}
f(1, 2);//logs 4
f(1234,2);//logs 4
```

But, honestly, it shouldn't really matter. The `arguments` object should be treated as a *read-only* object. It's a good idea to uphold the mantra "Don't change objects you don't own" in JS. It's a bad idea trying to change the `Object.prototype`, as it is not the best of ideas to change the behaviour of any object (`console`, `window`...) by deleting and adding methods at random.

If you want to get some more details on `arguments`, or anything else [MDN is there to help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments). I've not looked at all code examples there, but AFAIKT there's no code that effectively *changes* the `arguments` object. 
Some time ago I think I read an article my Douglas Crockford on the matter, where he gave an example of how changing the `arguments` object actually lead to unexpected behaviour (arguments swapping places and all that).

*Edit:*
I'd thought I'd not go into strict mode, but as bfavaretto's answer pointed out: strict-mode actually *does* make the `arguments` object a read-only object. That's terrific news, and now I have all the more reason to love the way JS is going. ES6 will introduce block scoping and probably make the `arguments` object read-only all the time (at least, I hope it will).

Comment: :) Absolutely. I had no intention of ever modifying function parameters in the way of that example. I was just trying to qualify what was stated in the book text in case there was some other underlying aspect that I'd missed or was not understanding what the author was highlighting.

Comment: I doubt ES6 will make it read-only all the time; unfortunately, they tend to avoid changes that are backward-incompatible.

Comment: @bfavaretto: A man can dream, can't he? Especially since, in the past MS was the one most in favour of staying compatible. But now they're breaking with tradition, and not very well represented on the newer markets (tablets, smartphones) they're not as dominant as once they were...

Answer (score 2):

It is supposed to work that way, unless in strict mode:

```
function foo(a) {
    "use strict";
    console.log(a, arguments[0]);
    a = 10;
    console.log(a, arguments[0]);
    arguments[0] = 20;
    console.log(a, arguments[0]);
}
foo(1);

// output:
// 1 1
// 10 1
// 10 20
```

The ES5 specification addresses that on [section 10.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6):

> **NOTE 1** For non-strict mode functions the array index (defined in 15.4) named data properties of an arguments object whose numeric name values are less than the number of formal parameters of the corresponding function object initially share their values with the corresponding argument bindings in the function’s execution context. This means that changing the property changes the corresponding value of the argument binding and vice-versa. This correspondence is broken if such a property is deleted and then redefined or if the property is changed into an accessor property. For strict mode functions, the values of the arguments object’s properties are simply a copy of the arguments passed to the function and there is no dynamic linkage between the property values and the formal parameter values.

*Maybe* it worked differently on ES3 (the previous version), but I doubt it (since they had to add a special case for strict mode).

Interesting fact: the presence of an `eval` call in the function can influence how the arguments object behave in some browsers, which is extremely weird. The use of the non-standard `functionName.arguments` reference also has an impact. See [Why does an unexecuted eval have an effect on behavior in some browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939736/why-does-an-unexecuted-eval-have-an-effect-on-behavior-in-some-browsers), and my answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

it will work that way only in strict mode..

```
 "use strict"
```

> The Arguments object has one very unusual feature. In non-strict mode,
>   when a function has named parameters, the array elements of the
>   Arguments object are aliases for the parameters that hold the function
>   arguments. The numbered elements of the Arguments object and the
>   parameter names are like two different names for the same variable.
>   Changing the value of an argument with an argument name changes the
>   value that is retrieved through the arguments[] array. Conversely,
>   changing the value of an argument through the arguments[] array
>   changes the value that is retrieved by the argument name. Here is an
>   example that clarifies this:
>
> function f(x) {
>       console.log(x);       // Displays the initial value of the argument
>       arguments[0] = null;  // Changing the array element also changes x!
>       console.log(x);       // Now displays "null" } This is emphatically not the behavior you would see if the Arguments object
>   were an ordinary array. In that case, arguments[0] and x could refer
>   initially to the same value, but a change to one would have no effect
>   on the other.
>
> This special behavior of the Arguments object has been removed in the
>   strict mode of ECMAScript 5. There are other strict-mode differences
>   as well. In non-strict functions, arguments is just an identifier. In
>   strict mode, it is effectively a reserved word. Strict-mode functions
>   cannot use arguments as a parameter name or as a local variable name,
>   and they cannot assign values to arguments.

Here is a great (and recent) article on this topic:
https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-8/function-arguments-and

I Suggest you use it :)